# How to extract filter code to local variable

Tags: scala

I'm filtering a list using this code :

```
linkVOList = linkVOList.filter(x => x.getOpen().>=(100))
```

The type x is inferred by Scala which is why it can find the .getOpen() method.

Can the code `'x => x.getOpen()'` be extracted to a local variable ? something like :

```
val xval = 'x => x.getOpen()'
```

and then :

```
linkVOList = linkVOList.filter(xval.>=(100))
```

I think this is difficult because the .filter method infers the type wheras I need to work out the type outside of the .filter method. Perhaps this can be achieved using `instaneof` or an alternative method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do what you are asking, but both ways will explicitly have to know the type of object they are working with:

```
case class VO(open:Int)

object ListTesting {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val linkVOList = List(VO(200))
    val filtered =  linkVOList.filter(x => x.open.>=(100))  

    val filterFunc = (x:VO) => x.open.>=(100)
    linkVOList.filter(filterFunc)

    def filterFunc2(x:VO) = x.open.>=(100)
    linkVOList.filter(filterFunc2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided any such information, I'll imply the following preconditions:

```
trait GetsOpen { def getOpen() : Int }

def linkVOList : List[GetsOpen]
```

Then you can extract the function like this:

```
val f = (x : GetsOpen) => x.getOpen()
```

or this:

```
val f : GetsOpen => Int = _.getOpen()
```

And use it like this:

```
linkVOList.filter( f.andThen(_ >= 100) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
import language.higherKinds
def inferMap[A,C[A],B](c: C[A])(f: A => B) = f

scala> val f = inferMap(List(Some("fish"),None))(_.isDefined)
f: Option[String] => Boolean = <function1>
```

Now, this is *not the value* but the function itself.  If you want the values, just

```
val opened = linkVOList.map(x => x.open)
(linkVOList zip opened).filter(_._2 >= 100).map(_._1)
```

but if you want the function then

```
val xfunc = inferMap(linkVOList)(x => x.open)
```

but you have to use it like

```
linkVOList.filter(xfunc andThen { _ >= 100 })
```

or

```
linkVOList.filter(x => xfunc(x) >= 100)
```

since you don't actually have the values but a function to compute the values.